# Install windows 7 on mac without product key

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, boot-camp, osx-mavericks

**My goal:** create a windows 7 partition on my macbook for dual boot purposes through Boot-Camp.

**The problem:** I bought the install disc for windows 7, but can no longer find the product key that came with the disc.

**The question:** How can I *legally* install the OS without knowing the product key (e.g. read the key from the disc itself).

**Caveat:** I only have access to Mac OSX at the moment, so any solution that requires windows will not work.

Comment: You can just boot from the DVD and avoid using Boot Camp, but make sure you made a separate partition for it first

Comment: @AlexYan It is an Air, so no DVD drive.

Comment: Bootable USB drives also work

Comment: You can install Windows without having the product key, and it will work for 30 days. This means that you aren't necessarily limited to OSX while you find a solution :)

Comment: Has this disc been used to install Windows on any other machines? If so, it may be possible to recover the key from them.